# How to test Connection Pooling in nodeJS using mogoDB Database?

Tags: connection, connection-pooling, connection-pool

How to test Connection Pooling in NodeJS using MongoDB Database?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having our app wait around for a request before connecting to the database we're going to have it connect when the application starts, and we're going to give ourselves a pool of connections to draw from as and when we need them.

Here we're using the [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) driver, which like most available [MongoDB drivers](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/) has an option that you can use to set the size of your connection pool. For this driver, it's called `poolSize`, and has a default value of 5. We can make use of the `poolsize` option by creating a database connection variable in advance, and letting the driver allocate available spaces as new connection requests come in:

```js
// This is a global variable we'll use for handing the MongoDB client
var mongodb;

// Connection URL
var url = '[connectionString]';

// Create the db connection
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {  
    assert.equal(null, err);
    mongodb=db;
    }
);
```

To change the size of the connection pool from the default, we can pass `poolSize` in as an option:

```js
// Create the database connection
MongoClient.connect(url, {  
  poolSize: 10
  // other options can go here
},function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    mongodb=db;
    }
);
```

Now we have a connection ready and waiting. To use our new connection, we just need to make use of our new global variable, `mongodb` when a request is made:

```js
// Use the connect method to connect to the server when the page is requested
app.get('/', function(request, response) {  
    mongodb.listCollections({}).toArray(function(err, collections) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        collections.forEach(function(collection) {
            console.log(collection);
        });
    })
    response.send('See console for a list of available collections');
});
```